# MongoDB: count the repetitive time of array element with MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

Say for every document of a collection, it has an string array. how could I count the repetitive time of every element of the array in all this collection? Right now I can find all the distinct element, but then Map Reduce function is a little tricky that I haven't fully understood.

```
Doc A    
{
_id:
name:
actors: ["a", "b", "c"]
}

Doc B     
{
_id:
name:
actors: ["a", "d"]
}

Doc C   
{
_id:
name:
actors: ["a", "c", "f"]
}
```

I wanne get a statistic result with a:3 b:1 c:2 d:1 f:1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative route that you could take is the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**. Considering the above collection as an example

**Populate test collection:**

```
db.collection.insert([
    { "_id" : 1, "name" : "ABC1", "actors": ["a", "b", "c"] },
    { "_id" : 2, "name" : "ABC2", "actors" : ["a", "d"] },
    { "_id" : 3, "name" : "XYZ1", "actors" : ["a", "c", "f"] }
])
```

**Using MongoDB 3.4.4 or newer:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$actors" },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$actors", "count": { "$sum": 1} } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id",
                "v": "$count"
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
    } }    
])
```

**Output**

```
{
    a: 3,
    b: 1,
    c: 2,
    d: 1,
    f: 1
}
```

---

**Using MongoDB 3.2 and below:**

The following aggregation pipeline operation uses the **[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** stage to output a document for each element in the `actors` array and the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)** stage to group the documents by the value in the `actors` array then 
counts the number of documents per each group (which gives the occurrence of the array elements as a group) by way of the **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$actors" },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$actors", "count": { "$sum": 1} } }
])
```

The operation returns the following results which would be a close match to your expectations but won't give you the documents as key/value pair:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "f",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "d",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "c",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "b",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is already close enough to what I wait for. I will look into it and try with a more complete example.